# ExtJs. JsonStore.insert() causes exception

Tags: exception, extjs, jsonstore

I have an `EditorGridPanel` with toolbar button to add new records. Everything works fine except one scenario. When I try to insert a record which already exists in database, server sends back:

```
{"success":false,"message":"already exists","data":{}}
```

but `grid` creates a new row marked with red triangle. If after that I try to insert a new record (even if it doesn't exist in database), everything works fine on the server side, but i get an 'uncaught exception' in firebug. It says:

```
'uncaught exception: Ext.data.DataReader: #realize was called with invalid remote-data. Please see the docs for DataReader#realize and review your DataReader configuration.'
```

why is that?

**EDIT**
I have found that:

When I try to insert a new record I use insert method which sends post request with parameter `data` to server (encode is true, listful is true):

```
data    [{"Name":"123"}]
```

and it gets from server:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"PositionId":"eef1d9f3-9fdf-4b87-9f6c-ef42231f4fed","Name":"123"}}
```

after that I try to create an item with the same name:

```
data    [{"Name":"123"}]
```

so I get:

```
{"success":false,"message":"already exists","data":{}}
```

from server.

The next time I try to create the right item the store sends array with 2 items

```
data    [{"Name":"1234"},{"Name":"123"}]
```

but server creates only the first (newest) item and sends back:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"PositionId":"1ff05c7f-d5fc-41cd-81f3-faabc225b2a6","Name":"1234"}}
```

So the error may occur because store asks server to create 2 items, but only one is send back.

So how to deal with it? is it possible to make store not to send the request for failed item again?

Answer (score 0):

try to switch off the autoSave opiton in the Store.

```
    this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
        id: 'store'
        ,autoSave: false 
        ,autoLoad: true
        ,writer: writer,  
        ,proxy: proxy
        ,reader: reader
        scope       : this
    });
```

see example for more info http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/writer/writer.html